# Scene rendering black when entering VR mode in A-Frame

Tags: aframe, webvr

I am using A-Frame 0.3.0. Everything renders fine on the screen, but when I enter VR mode, it renders black. I have tried the latest Chromium and Firefox Nightly builds from September. Even the A-Frame examples do not working.

```
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.3.1/aframe.min.js"></script>
<a-scene>
  <a-box color="red"></a-box>
</a-scene>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the September 2016 builds of Chromium and Firefox Nightly were updated to use the new WebVR 1.1 API spec, whereas A-Frame was working on WebVR 1.0 API spec.

This has been updated in A-Frame v0.3.2, where we have bumped VREffect to match the latest API changes.

```
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.3.2/aframe.min.js"></script>
<a-scene>
  <a-box color="red"></a-box>
</a-scene>
```

EDIT: additional breaking changes have been announced for WebVR 1.1, so things may break in future experimental versions of the browser temporarily until A-Frame updates again